# How to find the sum of the series $ \ \ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{16^n \pi^{2n+1}}{(2n)!} $ .

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to find the sum of the  series $ \ \ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{16^n \pi^{2n+1}}{(2n)!} $ .

**Answer:**

We know that $ \ \cos(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}=F(x) , say $ .

Now the given series can be written as $ \ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{16^n \pi^{2n+1}}{(2n)!} =\pi \left[ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{( 4\pi )^{2n}}{(2n)!} \right]-\pi ................(1) $

Now , $ \int_{0}^{4 \pi} \sin x dx \\ =  F(4 \pi)-F(0)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{( 4\pi )^{2n}}{(2n)!}  , \ by \ fundamental \ law \ of \ integral , \\ =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{( 4\pi )^{2n}}{(2n)!} -\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{( 0 )^{2n}}{(2n)!} \\ = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{( 4\pi )^{2n}}{(2n)!}  $ .

Now, $ \int_{0}^{4 \pi} \sin x dx =0 $

So, $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{( 4\pi )^{2n}}{(2n)!} =0 $ .

Hence from (1) , we have the sum

$ \ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{16^n \pi^{2n+1}}{(2n)!}\\ =\pi \cdot 0-\pi \\ =
 -\pi $

**I need confirmation of my work . Is there any help ?**

Comment: Since when does $\int_0^{4\pi}\cos x\;dx=\cos(4\pi)$? You are really close to the answer. There's just a silly mistake. Which you would best benefit from by finding yourself.

Comment: yes , I got my mistake. Thank you very much. So I think we have to use expansion of  $ \sin (x) \ $ . Right ?

Comment: Wonderfully written and almost there!  When you want to know the answer, ask [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) with the input `sum(n=1,infinity,(-1)^n 16^n pi^(2n+1) /((2n)!))` and you shall get your solution.

Comment: i did not get you,the meaning. I have to derive the sum step by step. Any help

Comment: I think it should be $0$, just plug in $4\pi$ in the expansion of $\cos{x}$ and substitute it into (1).

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking in another line:

$$\dfrac{(-1)^n16^n\pi^{2n+1}}{(2n)!}=\pi\cdot\dfrac{(i4\pi)^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(i4\pi)^{2n}}{(2n)!}=-1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(i4\pi)^{2n}}{(2n)!}=-1+\dfrac{e^{i4\pi}+e^{-i4\pi}}2$$

Now $e^{i\pi}=\cos\pi+i\sin\pi=-1$

Comment: But $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(i4\pi)^{2n}}{(2n)!}  \neq \dfrac{e^{i4\pi}+e^{-i4\pi}}2 $. So I think your calculation is wrong .

Comment: @mabmath, Why?   $$e^y=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\dfrac{y^r}{r!}$$ right?

Comment: How do you get  $ \frac{e^{i4 \pi}+e^{-i 4 \pi}}{2} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(i4 \pi)^{2n}}{(2n)!} $ ?

Comment: @mabmath, Please calculate $$e^y+e^{-y}$$

Answer (score 1):

Your series is simply $\pi (1-F(4\pi))=\pi (1-\cos 4\pi)=0.$

Comment: No, here $ F(x) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!} $ .  Thus $ F(0)=0 , \ \ not \ 1 \ $

Comment: $F(0)=\cos 0=1.$  The term $(-1)^nx^{2n}/(2n)!$ when n=0, is $x^0/0!$ which , when $x=0,$ is literally $0^0/0!.$ The convention is that $0^0=1, $ which saves a lot of writing, e.g. " A polynomial $p(x)=\sum_{j=0}^nA_jx^j\; $".